# Keeping user passwords safe in Java?

Tags: java, security, passwords, hash

I've come to a point when I need to pick a way how to safely keep user passwords in database and to be able to check if they match when user signs in in the website.

I'm using *Spring 2.5* at the moment, but upgrading slowly to *Spring 3*. What would you suggest me to keep the passwords safe? I know this question has been answered in similar forms here and there, but I would like to see some exact, **up-to-date** answer about how to do that, which could also protect against today's password hacking techniques.

What would be the most appropriate way of hashing passwords with salt? I mean what algorithm to use better if any at all? Should I use `bcrypt` instead and is `jBCrypt` a good lib for that? Is there any better way how to protect the passwords? What about using `Jasypt`? What techniques do you use to store the user passwords safely?

**Edit:** Even though i didn't get like very interesting and *detailish* answers I went with bcrypt/jBCrypt as it's seems the best choose. Feel free to discuss.

Comment: This article has some great information about Hashing password with a salt: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java

Comment: Don't you think it's pretty outdated if `bcrypt` suggest not to use password hashing with salt?

Comment: I'm not sure, looking at jbcrypt now it doesnt look very mature. I leave that up to someone else to answer.

Comment: @Richards: No, hashing using salts is not an outdated technique. The whole idea is that you employ a one-way function on the password + salt. This makes it quite hard to find the original password if a secure hash function is used. And never store passwords as plaintext!

Comment: @netrom, well yea, that was clear that I must not store them as plaintext! ;P I would like to see some good answer with an example tho. :/

Comment: @netrom, by the way, about the password + salt - i was referring to this article: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: @Richards: If you can try a lot of attempts very fast you will find the correct result at some point. But you have two factors; the original plaintext and the salt. If the password is very short then an attack might find it fast but if the salt, in that case, was very, very long it would instead take a long time to crack. So no, salts are not useless. Additionally, using salts also masks plaintexts that are the same.

Comment: @Richards: Those functions described in that article aren't general purpose hash functions. They are cryptographic hash functions, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function . As the article I posted above states, you should run the hash function multiple times (you decide the factor) which will slow it down. Your article fails to mention that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should use bcrypt/jBCrypt.   bcrypt is specifically designed to be slow, so it would take an infeasible amount of time to crack a password.

See [this blog post](http://www.katasoft.com/blog/2011/06/07/strong-password-hashing-part-2) on extra measures that you can use on top of using bcrypt for password hashing.

Answer (score 1):

SpringSecurity supports [password encoding](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-services.html#core-services-password-encoding) using hashing and salts.

Comment: Anything else you want to say? I've heard of `Spring Security` as a name and imagine what it does too. How good is it? Pros and cons? Bad..

Comment: @Richards: It's a pretty good and fully-featured web security framework. Apache Shiro is supposed to be easier to use, but since you're already using Spring, Spring Security should fit in pretty well. I've recently used in for exactly your requirements, it it worked very well.

Comment: It is good for implementing simple authentication / access control models.  For more complex models, things can get a bit tricky due to the inflexibility and opaqueness of the "namespace" configuration scheme.

Comment: I would recommend shiro for ACLs, spring-security and it's acl model is very hard to use imho.

Answer (score -5):

you can hash it using md5
code:

```
public static String StringHashing(String s) {

    MessageDigest m = null;
    try {
        m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {

    }
    m.update(s.getBytes(), 0, s.length());
    return (new BigInteger(1, m.digest()).toString(16));

}
```

Comment: md5 is vulnerable to rainbow table attacks.   See http://www.hacking-gurus.net/2009/04/30/crack-md5-password-hash-online/ for a list of links to md5 cracking sites.

Comment: @Richards: Just use `SHA-1`, `SHA-256` or `SHA-512` instead.

Comment: @netrom: Yea, but providing such awful information here where lot of users may check this answer is quite stupid.

Comment: MD5 and the SHA-* all have the problem of being extremely fast to hash and therefore vulnerable to brute force dictionary attacks.

Comment: @ericacm But it still takes a lot of effort to break a SHA hash.